# PL/SQL: Does SELECT INTO give the variable NULL if the value is NULL in the table?

Tags: plsql

I ask this question because I am trying to make a function that returns a value based on if the selected information in the table is NULL or not.  However, I cannot get the argument in the `if` statement to be true.

So, I have a `VARCHAR2` variable prepared, and then I use a select statement

```
SELECT info INTO lv_test
WHERE ...

IF lv_test != NULL THEN
    --Do not NULL stuff
ELSE
    --Do NULL stuff
```

Now, in the code I use specifically, I get values into `lv_test`, but unless I check for them directly, like `IF lv_test = 'NY'`, which becomes true and works, it won't become true. It will not work whenever I check for NULL values, nor does it work if I check for it to be `= ''` (initialized/default value).

My experience in SQL is fairly limited so this could be something basic I simply don't know yet.  So to answer my questions:

1. How do you check for NULL values from a `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement?
2. Why does my argument not work?

Comment: Try `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: That works, but why does that work, and not != ??

Comment: NULL is not equal to **anything**,  including another NULL.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm from a C++ and similar programming background, so I'm used to being able to check NULL with = and !=.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: To the close voters: it can't, *by definition*, be a "typo" if the question makes it clear the OP clearly intended to type the code that way!